# In Ruby, can I re-specify that an array is bound by () instead of []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm using Ruby / Rails to parse data from a MySQLDump file.. which very nicely includes all the data from all tables of a database, but not in Ruby array [] format.

e.g.  the MySQLDUMP might reference a table admins

```
INSERT INTO `admins` VALUES (1,'Superuser'),(2,'Normaluser')
```

It's easy for me extract from that the string:

```
"(1,'Superuser'),(2,'Normaluser')"
```

but I want to treat that as an array of arrays.. in other words get it to be:

```
[[1,'Superuser'],[2,'Normaluser']]
```

what I'm doing right now is:

```
vars = "(1,'Superuser'),(2,'Normaluser')"
vars = '[[' + vars[1..-3] + ']]'
vars = vars.gsub('),(','],[') #UGH!
array = YAML.load(vars)
```

which works, but any text content in the data that happens to be "),(" is going to break it.

So.. is there any way that I can instead do a YAML.load(vars) or similar where I specify that the the data is an array bounded with ( and )?

.. in other words,

```
vars = "(" + "(1,'Superuser'),(2,'Normaluser')" + ")"
array = YAML.load(vars).in_some_funky_way_where_array_boundaries_respecified
```

Thanks in advance.

K

Comment: Could you explain why you want to parse mysql dump file instead of importing it and interacting with db in a normal way?

Comment: Why is that better?  A dump file is a flat file representation of all the data. I only want some fields from some tables.  It's right there, and easy to parse out.. except for the problem I'm trying to solve. I don't see why going to the expense of generating an entire database is better - certainly not easier.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to load SQL as YAML, you should probably load SQL as SQL. I don't know if there are any SQL parsers for Ruby, though, which means that you will have to write your own. You can find the specification of SQL in [ISO/IEC 9075-1:2011
Information technology -- Database languages -- SQL -- Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=53681) and [ISO/IEC 9075-2:2011 Information technology -- Database languages -- SQL -- Part 2: Foundation (SQL/Foundation)](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=53682).

Or, you could let a SQL database do the SQL parsing for you and get the results back out of the database.

Comment: I am effectively writing the code that would be the core of an SQL parser..  and that involves solving this problem.